# Spring Boot Actuator - how to add custom logic to /shutdown endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my project I started using Spring Boot Actuator. I use `/shutdown` endpoint to gracefully stop the embedded Tomcat (this works well), but I also need to do some custom logic during shutdown. Is there any way, how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of two ways to perform some logic *before* shutting down the application:

1. Registering a `Filter`, it's a web application after all.
2. Intercepting the [`invoke`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/ShutdownEndpoint.java#L57) method using the `@Before` advice

### Servlet Filter

---

Since `/shutdown` is a Servlet endpoint, you can register a `Filter` to run before the `/shutdown` endpoint gets called:

```
public class ShutdownFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) 
                                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Put your logic here
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to register it:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "endpoints.shutdown.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new ShutdownFilter());
    registrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singleton("/shutdown"));

    return registrationBean;
}
```

### Defining an `@Aspect`

---

If you send a request to the `/shutdown` endpoint, assuming the shutdown endpoint is enabled and security does not block the request, the [`invoke`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/ShutdownEndpoint.java#L57) method will be called. You can define an `@Aspect` to intercept this method call and put your logic there:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ShutdownAspect {
    @Before("execution(* org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.ShutdownEndpoint.invoke())")
    public void runBeforeShutdownHook() {
        // Put your logic here
        System.out.println("Going to shutdown...");
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to enable the `AspectJAutoProxy`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Application { ... }
```

And `spring-aspects` dependency:

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-aspects'
```

Answer (score 4):

When it's invoked, the shutdown endpoint calls `close()` on the application context. This means that all of the usual mechanisms for running some custom logic during close processing are available.

For example, you could add a bean to the application context that implements `DisposableBean` or use the `destroyMethod` attribute of `@Bean` when you declare a bean via Java config:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="whateverYouWant")
public void Foo {
    return new Foo();
}
```

Comment: This should be the preferred approach, unless you need some beans that are destroyed before yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you make custom ShutdownEndpoint bean, You can add custom logic.

```
@Component
public class CustomShutdownEndpoint extends ShutdownEndpoint {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> invoke() {
        // Add your custom logic here            

        return super.invoke();
    }
}
```

In this way, you can change any logic spring-boot-actuator Endpoints.